# ASP.Net checkbox missing CSS class

Tags: asp.net

I have the following ASP.Net check box control added to a page:

`<asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" CssClass="myClass" />`

But when the page gets rendered it ignores the value of the CssClass property:

```
<input name="ctl00$mainContent$chkActive" id="ctl00_mainContent_chkActive" type="checkbox" value="on"/>
```

Any ideas how to apply the css class to the ASP.Net check box?

Thanks
Alan.

Comment: it is strange why CssClass it not rendered to class on input element..

Comment: It should work, there must be some other issue.

Comment: Are you certain there is no code in the code behind file that sets the CssClass to an empty string?

Comment: Hi TheGeekYouNeed there is definitely nothing in the code behind that sets the CssClass property to an empty string

Comment: The control seems to render with a surrounding span, and that span gets the CssClass value not the input itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, when you apply a CssClass to the ASP.Net check box control it applies the class to a span that wraps the check box. Because the css class isn't applied directly to the element it doesn't override the class that has been applied to all input elements.Therefore I used jQuery to select the element and apply the necessary style.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: Yes that is just what I needed as I had to update a asp.net webforms application and noticed the cssclass was adding to the outer span and then my jquery code for checkbox logic would not work.    This fix is nice,  I actually do this instead though     $("[id$=Out]").addClass("out");

Answer (score 25):

I found a different answer to this, you can use the property

```
MyCheckBox.InputAttributes["class"] = "myClass";
```

to assign a class directly to an asp checkbox from the codebehind.  Just noting this since I found this post through Google and the answer specified wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 9):

This post is quite old, but I'll post my solution to help anyone coming from google (like me).

You can use the child selector `>` in jQuery, because the wrapping `span` has the CssClass that you specified, and one `input` child. In your code:

```
$('.myClass > input').addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: charm for me too. I even added a different class than the one starting with:
   $('.form-control > input').addClass("biggercheckbox"); I put this in the  $(document).ready(function ()

Answer (score -1):

You could wrap it in a `span` with a class.

Comment: If you add a `<span>` before the `CheckBox`, don't forget to update your CSS.

Comment: The rendered code does this and that is the problem, especially when you migrate to newer boostrap versions, the input will not inherit from the span that asp generates as an input wrapper.

Answer (score -2):

You can alos just set the css class like

```
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbValittu" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Valittu")%>' Class="checBoks" />

Css class can look something like:
.checBoks input
{
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```