# Iterate asp.net checkbox, if any one is checked then unchecheck the checkbox with ID="All"

Tags: jquery, asp.net

HTML

```
 <div>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="All" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="ALL" ForeColor="Black" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Accepted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Contacted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay"  /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Text="Pending" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Text="Pre-Authorized" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" Text="Show Deleted" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox7" runat="server" Text="Treated" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="chkdisplay" />
</div>
```

Script i Tried(its not working).I have used `asp.net checkbok` and `cssclass` to iterate through I think `cssclass does not work` like `class selector`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chkdisplay').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#All').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
});
```

IS there any way i wand to use asp.net checkbox only.When i select any `checkbok between 2 to 7` i want checkbok of `ID="All"` to be unchecked
Thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with the right answer see here http://jsfiddle.net/hZFFr/3/

```
$('.chkdisplay').on('change blur', function () {;
    $('#All').attr('checked', !($('.chkdisplay').not(':checked').length));

})
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you can use attribute selector with `^` which gets all the elements beginning with the specified string..

```
$('[id^="CheckBox"]').each(function () {
```

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention: `CssClass` does not apply to the `input` element but to a `span` that wraps the input element. You should iterate each first children of `.chkdisplay` elements (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652851/asp-net-checkbox-missing-css-class)).

Something like:

```
$('.chkdisplay > input').each(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#All').prop('checked', false);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i am using asp.net controls so will $('.chkdisplay > input') input type work?

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your "All" Checkbox like :

```
<asp:CheckBox name="ChkTest" ID="All" runat="server" Checked="true" Text="ALL" ForeColor="Black" />
```

Instead of `$('#All').attr('checked', false);`

Try this one :

```
$('#<%= ChkTest.ClientID %>').attr('checked', false);
```