# Bootstrap Switch in Datagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

Im rendering a Datagrid in ASP.Net VB, I want to incorporate Bootstrap switch, but can only target one row

HTML:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Allow text" ItemStyle-Width="1px" HeaderStyle-Width="1px">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="cbtxt" runat="server" Checked='<%# Container.DataItem("allowtxt")%>'/>
   </ItemTemplate>          
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

JQUERY:

```
$("[id='ContentPlaceHolder1_dgNames_cbtxt_1']").bootstrapSwitch();
```

I could only get one working by accessing the chrome developer console, when i tried dropping the "1" at the end, it didnt work, it only work if i have the full ID, and nothing more. Is there a way around this?!

Display
[image]

Console
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could add a class to the checkbox, and use that as the JQuery selector?  e.g. `<asp:CheckBox ... CssClass="switch"/>` then `$(".switch").bootstrapSwitch()`.  However, it [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10179895/2278086) `CssClass` on `CheckBox` may create a wrapped `span` with the `class` set, so perhaps you would need `$("span.switch > input").bootstrapSwitch()`.

Comment: @Mark thanks for you response, and the link to the answer, appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question can be found over [here](http://www.example.com/) . The class i added to the `<asp:checkbox>` wasnt being picked up when the page rendered. So in reference to @Mark and the link above, i simply added a class to the checkbox through JQuery, before i initialized Bootstrap Switch:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").addClass("switch");
    $(".switch").bootstrapSwitch();
```